# ¿Cómo puedo refrescar un fragmento desde el Adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

En un fragmento, uso una lista de items para cargar una serie de anuncios de inmuebles, pero quiero que al pulsar en el botón de eliminar se actualice la lista de anuncios (para que así desaparezca el anuncio), lo mismo me gustaria para cuando se pulse el botón de editar. Cada elemento de la lsita es una MaterialCard. Los elementos se tratan en el adaptador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El método en el Fragment que carga la lista:

```
private fun cargarListView() {
    anuncios = appService.obtenerAnunciosUsuarioLogueado()
    listView.adapter = AnunciosAdapter(requireContext(), anuncios, activity)
}
```

Todo lo que pasa en el adaptador se resume en:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    var listItem = convertView
    if (listItem == null) listItem =
        LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_anuncio, parent, false)
    val currentAnuncio = anunciosList?.get(position)!!
    val informacion = appService.obtenerInformacionPreviaAnuncio(currentAnuncio)

    val deleteButton = listItem?.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.deleteButton)
    deleteButton!!.setOnClickListener {
        appDAL().delete(currentAnuncio)
        //Aquí debería de ir la actualización del fragmento
    }

    val editButton = listItem.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.editBtn)
    editButton.setOnClickListener { abrirEditarAnuncio(currentAnuncio) }
}
```

El método abrirEditarAnuncio es un simple cambio de fragmento.

Resumiendo, me gustaria que al pulsar el botón de borrar y al volver del fragmento de editar el anuncio, esta lista de anuncios se actualizara.

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem como usaria ese método, he probado a ponerlo en el listener del botón pero sigue igual

Comment: Debes eliminar el anuncio del dataset del adapter. Qué hace el método `appDAL().delete(currentAnuncio)`? Muestra más código..

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem `appDAL().delete(currentAnuncio)` borra el anuncio de la base de datos (ObjectBox en este caso) no hace nada más, solo toca la base de datos

Comment: escribiré una respuesta pero procura que el código en tus preguntas sea [completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El adapter tiene un dataset conformado por la lista de elementos que le pasaste a su constructor al momento de crearlo y el listView muestra los items que recibe de él. A menos que tengas un listener escuchando los cambios en tu base de datos y notificando al adapter, debes actualizar manualmente el dataset para mantenerlo sincronizado con tu base de datos.
No sé que tipo de adapter estés utilizando pero debe tener al menos los métodos `add`, `remove` y `notifyDataSetChanged` que puedes usar para esa tarea

```
deleteButton!!.setOnClickListener {
    // elimina el anuncio de la base de datos
    appDAL().delete(currentAnuncio)
    // elimina el anuncio del dataset
    remove(currentAnuncio)
    // actualiza la lista
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

En tu caso te convendría usar un RecyclerView en vez de un ListView. Su adapter tiene métodos más específicos como [notifyItemRemoved](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemRemoved(int)) que mejoran la performance. Aunque definitivamente sería más fácil si usaras las [nuevas listas](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists).