# Actualizar contenido listview

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, android-listview

tengo un listview que coge datos de un arraylist que he creado,he puesto que cuando haces click en un elemento de la lista lo elimine del arraylist,eso funciona, el problema es que aun sigue apareciendo en el listview aunque ya no se encuentre en el arraylist.
He visto en otras preguntas que recomendaban poner lo siguiente
((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

pero no me ha funcionado, aqui os dejo mi codigo por si sirve de ayuda
Gracias de antemano

```
package com.apps.practicafinalapps;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CarroFragment extends ListFragment {

public CarroFragment(){


}







@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    String[] names = new String[CarritoData.carritoActual.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < CarritoData.carritoActual.size(); i++)
    {
        names[i] = CarritoData.carritoActual.get(i).juego+"\t\t\t\t"+CarritoData.carritoActual.get(i).precio+"€";
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
    View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carro, container, false);

    TextView txtOne = (TextView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.textView23);
    txtOne.setText("TOTAL: "+CarritoData.getPrecioTotal()+"€");


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return returnView;
}








@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{

    CarritoData.carritoActual.remove(position);
    ((BaseAdapter) l.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();






}
```

}

Comment: esta respuesta no te sirve? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16708283/8166997

Comment: no, lo unico que funciona es si te cambias a otro fragment y luego vuelves al de la lista, entonces si te aparece con los datos actualizados

Comment: te sirve [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/450007/198326) respuesta?